# cd to a path containing spaces stored in a variable in Bash on macOS

Tags: bash, macos, cd, quoting

I have

```
x="/dir 1"
y=/dir\ 2
```

When I do `cd $x` or `cd $y` I get an error. I don't want to do `cd "$x"` because

1. I don't know which variables contain a path with spaces
2. It is inconvenient

Any workaround?

Comment: No. *Word-splitting* is applied after variable expansion by the shell for command line arguments. (that is what `"$x"` is to `cd`). You simply have to quote. (and now you know why Unix users hate windows paths with spaces sprinkled willy-nilly throughout)

Comment: Did you try `cd "$y"`? Quotes count!

Comment: "It is inconvenient." Switch to `zsh`, which doesn't (by default) perform word-splitting on unquoted parameter expansions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [shell option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) that tells Bash to check if the argument to `cd` is a variable that contains a path:

```
shopt -s cdable_vars
y='/dir 2'
cd y
```

where `cd y` is equivalent to `cd "$y"`.

From the manual:

> `cdable_vars`
>   If this is set, an argument to the `cd` builtin command that is not a directory is assumed to be the name of a variable whose value is the directory to change to.

---

Recent versions of [bash-completion](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion) check if the shell option is set and offer to complete variable names for `cd`, but to get this to work, the shell option has to be set before the completion is loaded.

The default completion setting for `cd` is

```
complete -F _cd -o nospace cd pushd
```

To add variable completion to this, it has be changed to

```
complete -v -F _cd -o nospace cd pushd
```

Comment: That's a cool trick for all cdable variables, include those with no spaces.

Comment: One drawback, though, is there's no tab completion here. With a longer variable name, it may be easier to type `cd "$SOME_L<tab>"` than `cd SOME_LONG_PATH_NAME`.

Comment: @chepner Bash-completion seems to support it (see [GitHub](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/bash_completion#L1715)), but you have to re-source the `bash_completion` script after setting the shell option. Or, alternatively, run `complete -v -F _cd -o nospace cd pushd` manually (the `-v` is the important bit).

Comment: `bash_completion` is a separate package from `bash` itself, though.

Comment: @chepner Sure - but if you don't have bash-completion, you can still get tab completion for variables with `cd` by adding `-v` to whatever completion there is currently set.